# Navbar working in ie9 but not in chrome - bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have the below `CSS` for modifying the `navbar`

CSS:

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #0A4BCC;
    border-color: #0A4BCC;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color:  #E5E4E2;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color:  #5EFB6E;
}
```

_Layout page:

```
<div id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
            //     
    </div>
</div>
```

This woks fine in `IE 9` but doent work in `Chrome`. Can you please suggest as to what could be the problem?

In Chrome, it is applying the `hover-font`, `default-font` but not the `background-color` for navbar.

Comment: worked for me: http://jsbin.com/cojuwiri/1/edit

Comment: its working for me on the link you provided but not when i run from Visual Studio.